# AttributeError message while trying to save form data to db

Tags: python, forms, django-views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from .forms import RegisterForm

def register(feauest):
  if request.method=='POST':
     form=RegisterForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
         name=form.cleaned_data['username']
         password=form.cleaned_data['password']
         email=form.cleaned_data['email']
         gender=form.cleaned_data['gender']

         form.save()

form=RegisterForm()
return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})'
```

When I run it I get an `AttributeError: 'RegisterForm' object has no attribute 'save'`

Please can anyone help me fix it.

Comment: edited your question. Please check the edit if it is what you actually tried because it seemed that your code has lot of indentation problems

Comment: Where do you call `register()`?

Comment: You never use the parameter `feauest`. Is that supposed to be `request`?

Comment: Yes thats request.